# Pine Script - Compare High / Low with Bollinger Band

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I wanted to compare bollinger band top / bottom with high / low.  How can I do so?  I tried to compare with below

```
E=high[2]>=ta.bb(close[2],20,+2)
F=low[2]<=ta.bb(close[2],20,-2)
```

but it is not allowing.  How do I rectify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pinescript function ta.bb() send back 3 series like this :

```
[middle, upper, lower] = ta.bb(close[2], 20, 20)
```

So in your code you should first calculate your 3 variables, and compare the variable that you want with your high or low, for example  :

```
E = high[2] >= middle
```

Comment: So this means that I code to calculate upper and lower and middle BB values? Since I don't need middle, i can ignore that i guess?

Comment: [middle, upper, lower]... this needs to be same order and all three written for formula to work!!  never expected this.  there is no need to code BB values. thank you for the guidance.